# Probablity of number of concurrent overlapping events

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

This is a problem for work I've been wrestling with. 20 people will be using a software app for 2 hours each day randomly distributed over the course of a week. What are the probabilities for the maximum # of concurrent app users during the week. IOW, what are the probabilities that the number of people using the app at the same time does not exceed n.

At the risk of biasing others' thoughts about this, I used a binomial distribution to calculate the probability of the # of concurrent users <= n at any particular point in time. But then unsure how to translate this to a probability of n concurrent users happening at any point during the week. I considered using a binomial distribution again for this, but I'm thinking it's maybe not appropriate because there are not a discreet number of trials involved, but rather continuous time.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "randomly distributed", do you have a particular probability distribution in mind? For example, are these 20 people are located in the same place; if so, are you assuming that they are more likely to use it during the day time than the night time? Also, is it necessarily 2 consecutive hours, or could a person's two hours be broken up into smaller chunks?

Comment: If the 2 hours is uniformly randomly distributed within a day, then at each point of time the probability of an app user online is 2/24. Then number of concurrent users becomes a binomial distribution with p=2/24 and n=20...

Comment: @JonathanPal, I was meaning the assumption of uniformly randomly distributed and assuming 2 consecutive hours, for simplicity.

Comment: @Kryvtsov, yes, I was able to compute the probabilities of the number of concurrent users at any particular point in time by the way you pointed out, but my question is how do I then figure out the probability of the max # of concurrent users over the whole time period.

Comment: You might want to formulate the question, IDK what "the probability of the max # of concurrent users over the whole time period" really means.

Comment: Hi @Kryvtsov, how is this: 

What is the probability distribution for the maximum number of concurrent app users during a week, given that 20 people will be using the software app for 2 hours each day, uniformly randomly distributed?